# execute javascript method after method excution complete?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I want execute below `callback()`method after completion of  process `document.getElementById('btnDownload').click();` method. `click()` is the code behind method. That means, I mean after complete process of `click()` then excute `callback()` method.

Because my modelpop is not hiding in code behind. So I want hide in javascript method.

```
function LoadPopup() { 
    //  find the popup behavior 
    this._popup = $find('mdlPopup'); 
    // show the popup 
    this._popup.show(); 

    // synchronously run the server side validation ... 
    document.getElementById('btnDownload').click(); 
   callback();          
} 


 function callback() { 
    this._popup = $find('mdlPopup'); 
    //  hide the popup 
    this._popup.hide(); 
    alert("hi");
```

}

Comment: What does `document.getElementById('btnDownload').click();` trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the code wait for the result of the first function.

```
if(document.getElementById('btnDownload').click())
   callback();
```

If the function returns true then run the second function.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#btnDownload").click(function () {
    jQuery("#mdlPopup").fadeOut(800);
});

/* to call that anonymous function again, just use the trigger() method */
// jQuery("#btnDownload").trigger("click");
```